# How can I remove duplicate words in a string with Python?

Tags: python, string, duplicates

Following example:

```
string1 = "calvin klein design dress calvin klein"
```

How can I remove the second two duplicates `"calvin"` and `"klein"`?

The result should look like

```
string2 = "calvin klein design dress"
```

only the second duplicates should be removed and the sequence of the words should not be changed!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
def unique_list(l):
    ulist = []
    [ulist.append(x) for x in l if x not in ulist]
    return ulist

a="calvin klein design dress calvin klein"
a=' '.join(unique_list(a.split()))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's O(N²) – the `in` goes through the whole `ulist` each time. Don't use it for long lists.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. I found that list comprehension part about 2 years ago on SO itself. Have been using it ever since.

Comment: @Petr. Thats true. I provided it here under the assumption that the list is not going to be too long.

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Comment: @lazyr :). The above code is just a short and sweet code. Not be taken too seriously with arbitrarily large lists.

Comment: I find your use of append in a list comprehension disturbing.

Comment: A list comprehension is inappropriate and should not be used unless you're using the output. Use a proper `for x in l: if x not in ulist: ulist.append(x)`.

Answer (score 58):

```
string1 = "calvin klein design dress calvin klein"
words = string1.split()
print (" ".join(sorted(set(words), key=words.index)))
```

This sorts the set of all the (unique) words in your string by the word's index in the original list of words.

Answer (score 13):

In Python 2.7+, you could use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
s = "calvin klein design dress calvin klein"
print ' '.join(OrderedDict((w,w) for w in s.split()).keys())
```

Comment: `' '.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s.split()))`.

Answer (score 8):

Cut and paste from the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

I really wish they could go ahead and make a module out of those recipes soon. I'd very much like to be able to do `from itertools_recipes import unique_everseen` instead of using cut-and-paste every time I need something.

Use like this:

```
def unique_words(string, ignore_case=False):
    key = None
    if ignore_case:
        key = str.lower
    return " ".join(unique_everseen(string.split(), key=key))

string2 = unique_words(string1)
```

Comment: I timed a few of these… this one is very fast, even for long lists.

Comment: @lazyr: As for your wish, it turns out you can do *exactly* that. Just install [the package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/itertools_recipes) from PyPI.

Comment: @Petr This news does not suprise me in the slightest. I'd be amazed if there *weren't* a PyPI package for just that. What I meant was that it should be part of the *included batteries* in python, since they are used so frequently. I'm rather puzzled as to why they're not.

Answer (score 7):

```
string2 = ' '.join(set(string1.split()))
```

**Explanation**:

`.split()` - it is a method to split string to list (without params it split by spaces)
`set()` - it is type of unordered collections that exclude dublicates
`'separator'.join(list)` - mean that you want to join list from params to string with 'separator' between elements

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: This potentially changes the order of the words in the string.

Comment: This will not remove duplicates if you want to split on other element than space.
fe:  `"cisco, cisco systems, cisco".join(set(a.split()))` will output: `'cisco, systems, cisco'`

Answer (score 5):

```
string = 'calvin klein design dress calvin klein'

def uniquify(string):
    output = []
    seen = set()
    for word in string.split():
        if word not in seen:
            output.append(word)
            seen.add(word)
    return ' '.join(output)

print uniquify(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set to keep track of already processed words.

```
words = set()
result = ''
for word in string1.split():
    if word not in words:
        result = result + word + ' '
        words.add(word)
print result
```

Comment: Note that `set` is a built-in type. No need to import it (unless you use an *ancient* version of Python).

Comment: You should make `result` a list, `append` the words to it, and then `return " ".join(result)` in the end. This is [much more efficient](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/).

Answer (score 2):

Several answers are pretty close to this but haven't quite ended up where I did:

```
def uniques( your_string ):    
    seen = set()
    return ' '.join( seen.add(i) or i for i in your_string.split() if i not in seen )
```

Of course, if you want it a tiny bit cleaner or faster, we can refactor a bit:

```
def uniques( your_string ):    
    words = your_string.split()

    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add

    def add(x):
        seen_add(x)  
        return x

    return ' '.join( add(i) for i in words if i not in seen )
```

I think the second version is about as performant as you can get in a small amount of code. (More code could be used to do all the work in a single scan across the input string but for most workloads, this should be sufficient.)

Answer (score 1):

Question: Remove the duplicates in a string

```
 from _collections import OrderedDict

    a = "Gina Gini Gini Protijayi"

    aa = OrderedDict().fromkeys(a.split())
    print(' '.join(aa))
   # output => Gina Gini Protijayi
```

Comment: Starting from Python 3.7, insertion order is guaranteed in dicts. So no need for OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy function
make an import its better to have an alias for the import (as np)

```
import numpy as np
```

and then you can bing it like this
for removing duplicates from array you can use it this way

```
no_duplicates_array = np.unique(your_array)
```

for your case if you want result in string you can use

```
no_duplicates_string = ' '.join(np.unique(your_string.split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicate words from sentence and preserve the order of the words you can use `dict.fromkeys` method.

```
string1 = "calvin klein design dress calvin klein"

words = string1.split()

result = " ".join(list(dict.fromkeys(words)))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

11 and 2 work perfectly:

```
    s="the sky is blue very blue"
    s=s.lower()
    slist = s.split()
    print " ".join(sorted(set(slist), key=slist.index))
```

and 2

```
    s="the sky is blue very blue"
    s=s.lower()
    slist = s.split()
    print " ".join(sorted(set(slist), key=slist.index))
```

Comment: How is this `key` argument work? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicate or repeated words from a text file or string using following codes -

```
from collections import Counter
for lines in all_words:

    line=''.join(lines.lower())
    new_data1=' '.join(lemmatize_sentence(line))
    new_data2 = word_tokenize(new_data1)
    new_data3=nltk.pos_tag(new_data2)

    # below code is for removal of repeated words

    for i in range(0, len(new_data3)):
        new_data3[i] = "".join(new_data3[i])
    UniqW = Counter(new_data3)
    new_data5 = " ".join(UniqW.keys())
    print (new_data5)


    new_data.append(new_data5)


print (new_data)
```

P.S. -Do identations as per required.
Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Without using the split function (will help in interviews)

```
def unique_words2(a):
    words = []
    spaces = ' '
    length = len(a)
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        if a[i] not in spaces:
            word_start = i
            while i < length and a[i] not in spaces:
                i += 1
            words.append(a[word_start:i])
        i += 1
    words_stack = []
    for val in words:  #
        if val not in words_stack:  # We can replace these three lines with this one -> [words_stack.append(val) for val in words if val not in words_stack]
            words_stack.append(val)  #
    print(' '.join(words_stack))  # or return, your choice


unique_words2('calvin klein design dress calvin klein')
```

Answer (score 0):

##### initializing list

```
listA = [ 'xy-xy', 'pq-qr', 'xp-xp-xp', 'dd-ee']

print("Given list : ",listA)
```

##### using `set()` and `split()`

```
res = [set(sub.split('-')) for sub in listA]
```

##### Result

```
print("List after duplicate removal :", res)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

# Calea către fișierul tău
file_path = "g:\Pyton+ChatGPT\dictionar_no_duplicates.txt"

# Citește conținutul fișierului
with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    text = file.read()

# Elimină cuvintele duplicate
result = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)', '', text)

# Elimină spații suplimentare sau virgule consecutive
result = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', result).strip().replace(" ,", ",")

# Rescrie fișierul cu conținutul fără duplicate
with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(result)
```

**OR THIS**

```
def remove_duplicates(words):
    words_stack = []
    for val in words:
        if val not in words_stack:
            words_stack.append(val)
    return words_stack

input_file = r'g:\Pyton+ChatGPT\dictionar.txt'
output_file = r'g:\Pyton+ChatGPT\dictionar_no_duplicates.txt'

with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()

unique_words = remove_duplicates(words)

with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for word in unique_words:
        f.write(word + '\n')

print("Duplicate removal completed.")
```

**OR THIS**

```
import re

# Calea către fișierul tău
file_path = "g:\Pyton+ChatGPT\dictionar_no_duplicates.txt"

# Citește conținutul fișierului
with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    text = file.read()

# Crează o listă pentru cuvintele eliminate
removed_words = []

# Funcție callback pentru a adăuga cuvintele duplicate în listă
def replace_and_collect(match):
    word = match.group(1)
    if word not in removed_words:
        removed_words.append(word)
    return ''

# Elimină cuvintele duplicate și virgula asociată folosind funcția callback
result = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\b,?(?=.*\b\1\b)', replace_and_collect, text)

# Elimină spații suplimentare sau virgule consecutive
result = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', result).strip().replace(" ,", ",").strip(", ")

# Rescrie fișierul cu conținutul fără duplicate
with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(result)

# Afișează informații despre cuvintele eliminate
print(f"Numărul de cuvinte duplicate eliminate: {len(removed_words)}")
print(f"Cuvintele eliminate: {', '.join(removed_words)}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that simply by getting the set associated to the string, which is a mathematical object containing no repeated elements by definition. It suffices to join the words in the set back into a string:

```
def remove_duplicate_words(string):
        x = string.split()
        x = sorted(set(x), key = x.index)
        return ' '.join(x)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: This potentially changes the order of the words in the string.

Comment: Thanks @parvus I have modified my answer