# Python Duplicate Words in Text File

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a txt file

the text file looks like this:

Still not working.

> ['None']['Vega~']['Vega~']['Vega~']['8^)->-<']['violence']['puker']['Zanaz']['Funk']['8^)->-<']['8^)->-<']['8^)->-<']['Vega~']['violence']['Zanaz']['Funk']['puker']['Vega~']['Vega~']['Vega~']['8^)->-<']['violence']['puker']['Zanaz']['None']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Leafy']['Judge69']['David']['lilwade']['Pity.']['artofwar']['Hazecloud']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Judge69']['Leafy']['David']['lilwade']['Hazecloud']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Leafy']['David']['Pity.']['lilwade']['artofwar']['Judge69']

I need to remove all the duplicates so each name should only show one time, also it must keep the order they are in.

```
   fo = open('C:\Python26\myfile.txt','r')
   name_cache = fo.readlines()
   typea = name_cache[0]

   def unique_list(l):
      ulist = []
      [ulist.append(x) for x in l if x not in ulist]
      return ulist

   mast =' '.join(unique_list(typea.split()))
   print mast
```

Comment: And what have you done till now? This is not a code-writing service. If you are stuck on anything in your trials we can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate words in a string with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794208/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-words-in-a-string-with-python)

Comment: How can you `split()` on this input?  There doesn't seem to be any whitespace between each `['someName']` entry.

Comment: You want to keep the square brackets around the words?

Comment: No keeping the brackets isn't an issue just the order and the names.

Comment: Is there any whitespace in the text file at all?  Or is it all in one line?

Comment: Its all just one line @ james

Answer (score 3):

First remove the leading `[` and trailing `]`.  Then `split` on `][`.  For example

```
>>> x="['None']['Vega~']['Vega~']"
>>> x.rstrip(']').lstrip('[').split('][') 
["'None'", "'Vega~'", "'Vega~'"]
```

Then call your `unique_list`.

```
>>> y = x.rstrip(']').lstrip('[').split('][') 
>>> unique_list(y)
["'None'", "'Vega~'"]
```

Then you can easily format it to whatever you want (i.e. to a string).

Note that `rstrip` and `lstrip` are each O(n).  So it might be better to do `x[1:-1]`.  This assumes you are 100% certain that the input is of the given form (starts with `[` and ends with `]`)

This has the same O(n) time complexity as hashing every word (adding to a python set), but maintains the original order, and gets to use your (pretty neat) `unique_list` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import collections
def unique_list(l): return list(OrderedSet(l))
```

Also, `typea` is just a string with no whitespace. To split names, do this:

```
typea = typea.replace('[', '').split(']') # typea is now a list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "['None']['Vega~']['Vega~']['Vega~']['8^)->-<']['violence']['puker']['Zanaz']['Funk']['8^)->-<']['8^)->-<']['8^)->-<']['Vega~']['violence']['Zanaz']['Funk']['puker']['Vega~']['Vega~']['Vega~']['8^)->-<']['violence']['puker']['Zanaz']['None']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Leafy']['Judge69']['David']['lilwade']['Pity.']['artofwar']['Hazecloud']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Judge69']['Leafy']['David']['lilwade']['Hazecloud']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Lawn']['Leafy']['David']['Pity.']['lilwade']['artofwar']['Judge69']"
ss = s[1:-1]
l = []
for i in ss.split(']['):
    if i not in l:
        l.append(i)
r = ' '.join(l)
```

With the result:

```
"'None' 'Vega~' '8^)->-<' 'violence' 'puker' 'Zanaz' 'Funk' 'Lawn' 'Leafy' 'Judge69' 'David' 'lilwade' 'Pity.' 'artofwar' 'Hazecloud'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution that keeps the brackets around the names:

```
fo = open('myfile.txt','r')
name_cache = fo.readlines()[0]
names = []
for name in name_cache.replace('][', '],[').split(','):
    if name not in names:
        names.append(name)

print(names)
```