# Remove adjacent duplicate words in a string with Python?

Tags: python, string, duplicates

How would I remove adjacent duplicate words in a string. For example
'Hey there There' -> 'Hey there'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794208/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-words-in-a-string-with-python if you want no duplicate words at all... Or do you only want to remove adjacent duplicates?

Comment: These words are not adjacent though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `re.sub` with a backreference we can try:

```
inp = 'Hey there There'
output = re.sub(r'(\w+) \1', r'\1', inp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(output)  # Hey there
```

The regex pattern used here says to:

```py
(\w+)  match and capture a word
[ ]    followed by a space
\1     then followed by the same word (ignoring case)
```

Then, we just replace with the first adjacent word.

Comment: What does r mean above?

Comment: @user1655130 An `r` preceding a Python string indicates that it is a _raw_ string.  We use raw strings because it can make it easier to write regex, avoiding escaping.

Comment: from a learning perspective - how would you do this with recursion?

Comment: I suggest opening a new question, as using some kind of recursive approach is very different from my current answer (but maybe I can post _another_ answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, it wont let me ask a similar question. Thanks for your help

Comment: `def removeConsecutiveDuplicateWors(s):
    st = s.split()
    if len(st) < 2:
        return " ".join(st)
    if st[0] != st[1]:
        nw =  ("".join(st[0])) +" "+ removeConsecutiveDuplicateWors(" ".join(st[1:]))
        return nw
    return removeConsecutiveDuplicateWors(" ".join(st[1:]))
  

string = 'I am a duplicate duplicate word in a sentence. How I can be be be removed?'
print(removeConsecutiveDuplicateWors(string))  
`

Answer (score 3):

```
inp = 'Hey there There'
output = re.sub(r'\b(\w+) \1\b', r'\1', inp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(output)  # Hey there

inp = 'Hey there eating?'
output = re.sub(r'\b(\w+) \1\b', r'\1', inp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(output)  # Hey there eating?
```

`\b` ensures word boundary and captures the entire word instead of character. The second test case ("Hey there eating?") does not work with https://stackoverflow.com/a/68481181/8439676 answer given by Tim Biegeleisen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove adjacent duplicate words recursively

```
   def removeConsecutiveDuplicateWors(s):
        st = s.split()
        if len(st) < 2:
            return " ".join(st)
        if st[0] != st[1]:
            nw =  ("".join(st[0])) +" "+ removeConsecutiveDuplicateWors(" ".join(st[1:]))
            return nw
        return removeConsecutiveDuplicateWors(" ".join(st[1:]))
      
    
    string = 'I am a duplicate duplicate word in a sentence. How I can be be be removed?'
    print(removeConsecutiveDuplicateWors(string))
```

output : I am a duplicate word in a sentence. How I can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

[Rohit Sharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69085340/21371964) should be accepted, as it does in fact take word boundaries into account. The original answer would incorrectly change `Hey there eating` to `Hey thereating`

**Alternatively, one could use the following regex** (which will produce a slightly different output in some scenarios; see examples below):

```py
my_output = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)(?:\W+\1\b)+', r'\1', my_input, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

*Example 1:*

INPUT: `Buying food food in the supermarket`

ROHITS VERSION OUTPUT: `Buying food in the supermarket`

ABOVE VERSION OUTPUT: `Buying food in the supermarket`

*Example 2:*

INPUT: `Food: Food and Beverages`

ROHITS VERSION OUTPUT: `Food: Food and Beverages` (unchanged)

ABOVE VERSION OUTPUT: `Food and Beverages`

**Explanation:**

“\b”: A word boundary. Boundaries are needed for special cases. For example, in “My thesis is great”, “is” wont be matched twice.

“\w+” A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

“\W+”: A non-word character: [^\w]

“\1”: Matches whatever was matched in the 1st group of parentheses, which in this case is the (\w+)

“+”: Match whatever it's placed after 1 or more times

**Credits:**

I adapted this code to Python but it originates from [this geeksforgeeks.org post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicate-words-from-sentence-using-regular-expression/)